# TWSz update application via Java API

Tags: workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I try to update application in TWSz via Java API but when application has defined run cycles with Out of Effect date set to  71/12/31, TWSz returns error:
EQQX375E THE RUN CYCLE VALIDITY END 720101 IS INVALID OR BEFORE/AT THE START

In every application, before update, it I have to check that there is run cycles and if are, check the Out Of Effect dates. If OOE == 71/12/31 update it to 31-12-71 using setValidTo but this is very inconvenient. Is there any other way to update application without updating Run Cycles?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that going forward and back, the date gets an additional day, wrapping to the TWSz minimal date 720101 (Jan 1st, 1972).

Do you make any conversion of the java Date that is returned by the API before send it back to the update?

I suggest to verify the date and time of the Java Date that is returned by the API on the get, and compare it with the Java Date that you are passing to the update.

For TWSz APIs, the Java Date object that contains a date without a time (like the validTo) should be set to the midnight GMT of the date they  represent.

Comment: I don't make any Date conversion because I don't update Run cycle. I only updating dependency. getValidTo() returns Thu Dec 31 01:00:00 CET 2071

Comment: The same situation is via TDWC. RC ending date is automatically fill with date  12/31/2071, however, when I click "Save" get:The operation on object DM#TDWC(6/28/16) was not completed because the following error occurred: EQQX375E THE RUN CYCLE VALIDITY END 720101 IS INVALID OR BEFORE/AT THE START